# React-redux to add product to cart through single button

Tags: react-redux

How to add multiple products in cart through a single add button using react redux. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Find implementations here:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/naughty-morning-wzpv3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Here on every button click, 2 products will be added.